# When using request it's returning random strings and letters instead of XML

Tags: node.js, xml, npm, request, postman

I'm trying to retrieve the XML of this API: https://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=4562735369 when I use postman it returns the XML correctly.

What I'm trying to get:

```xml
<roblox xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.roblox.com/roblox.xsd" version="4">
  <External>null</External>
  <External>nil</External>
  <Item class="Decal" referent="RBX0">
    <Properties>
      <token name="Face">5</token>
      <string name="Name">Decal</string>
      <float name="Shiny">20</float>
      <float name="Specular">0</float>
      <Content name="Texture">
        <url>http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=4562735350</url>
      </Content>
      <bool name="archivable">true</bool>
    </Properties>
  </Item>
</roblox>
```

What I'm getting:
`` �u�_K�0���Cɻ�u[F� L��^��n �IIҵ~{�6��9�Czί���PkVʴI[*�fm)K�I�}5h�f�LF�na���'`B���g�kX�����_I�<ע��ə6o�DWq��?7�{i��I�o��)![�&����)a�IB�Z�Vs�t����S�x/�D(�\NQpE���}N>���wk*�^��Jм�B�h޵�6!,�ЋG�y+�6B�΄�A�Hn��>��B�o��)�^>CU(j�-a�܃�>l�Ol}m��@�V���u��;�Χ���v�M�������1*�q+ ��+���Bg?UR�n!i�d����\� ``

My code:

```js
// Packages
const express = require("express");
const xmlparser = require("express-xml-bodyparser");
const getQueryParam = require("get-query-param");
const request = require("request");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const colors = require("colors");

// Configuration
const PORT = 3000;
const RATE_LIMIT_WINDOW_TIME = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 minutes
const RATE_LIMIT_REQUEST_MAX = 100;

// Functions
function logInformation(tag, data) {
  console.log(colors.yellow(`[${tag}]: `) + colors.underline(data));
}

// express app
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: RATE_LIMIT_WINDOW_TIME,
  max: RATE_LIMIT_REQUEST_MAX
});

const app = express();
logInformation("Startup", "Created express server instance.");

app.use(limiter);
logInformation("Startup", "Started using app rate limiter");

app.use(xmlparser());
logInformation("Startup", "Started using XML body parser");

// api

app.get("/getDecalID/:id", (req, res) => {
  let imageId = req.params.id;

  if (imageId) {
    request(`http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=4562735369`, function(
      error,
      response,
      body
    ) {
      if (!error) {
        logInformation("Body", body);
        res.send(body);
      } else {
        res
          .status(500)
          .json({ error: "Error while sending request to roblox's API" });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "imageId not provided or found." });
  }
});

// Listen
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(colors.green("Running: ") + `http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Postman Screenshot:
[image: Postman]

I'm not sure what else to do because everytime that I send the request it just returns the random characters. I need the XML so I can parse it into data. I know it's possible because postman is able to get the XML but I don't know why I can't get it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Request** Doesn't allow you to use XML and parse it so I found [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) that's very similar to request and returns the XML data.